# How can I calculate NSString max length which UILabel can contain without truncate the text?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, uilabel

I have two UILabels, one above the other.
The top one has fixed size (2 Lines), and the bottom one can expand (0 lines).
The text which I using for the labels can be short and sometimes it can be very long.
How can I calculate the first UILabel max string length without cut a word in the middle?

//Here is the code which create the 2 labels.

```
    titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 200, 50)]; 
    titleView.numberOfLines = 2;

    titleView2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 250, 100)];
    titleView2.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem with this method:

```
+ (int)getSplitIndexWithString:(NSString *)str frame:(CGRect)frame andFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    int length = 1;
    int lastSpace = 1;
    NSString *cutText = [str substringToIndex:length];
    CGSize textSize = [cutText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 500)];
      while (textSize.height <= frame.size.height)
      {
          NSRange range = NSMakeRange (length, 1);
          if ([[str substringWithRange:range] isEqualToString:@" "])
          {
              lastSpace = length;
          }
          length++;
          cutText = [str substringToIndex:length];
          textSize = [cutText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 500)];
      }
      return lastSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize textSize=[someString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:sizeConstraint];
```

Then you can access the width and height:

```
float height=textSize.height;
float width=textSize.width;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that method, but it doesn't solve my problem I think. I need to split the string in the correct index without truncate a word in the middle.